# Win10 and scipy : unsupported wheel

Tags: python, scipy, pip, installation

I've been struggling for the past two days with SciPy. I'm installing it at work on a fresh new windows 10 build (yeah I know...). Python 64 installed, everything running smoothly but can"t find any way to install SciPy.

I've downloaded the wheels from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy), I've tried scipy-0.19.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl and scipy-0.19.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl but it always comes up with the same error (tried pip3 and pip):

```
$ pip3 install scipy-0.19.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
scipy-0.19.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Any idea? I've tried the pip updates, python updates and nothing seems to work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried installing any other packages this way? Do they fail or is it just scipy?

Comment: Other packages work fine, it's just scipy. I've installed the tensorflow nightly build this way.

EDIT : it might come from the version as I'm not using cpn but can't find any wheel name as scipy-XXX-none-win_amd64.whl...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure compatibility between your python version and the wheel file. For the wheel file, this is denoted by cpxx. For example, cp35 is for python3.5